# Deploy PHP application and restrict code changes

Tags: php, encryption

Can we deploy PHP application on a client server and restrict client from viewing or editing any of the code.

For example, if i don't want my client to take the code to some other developers without my permission.

Comment: This is what signed contracts are for. Legally arguable and defensible contracts.

Comment: If that's how you feel, sounds like a bad job to take...

Comment: There's theoretically no way for you to stop a guy from modifying code running on his own server the way he wants, so anything you do can only slow him down... but that's not what you should be worrying about, you should code the site, take the paycheck, and go on to the next job.  If you can put sites together you can find reliable jobs without having to DRM your products.  Red Hat doesn't make billions by code obsfucation, quite the opposite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into PHP code encryption in the past, but it is a fundamentally bad idea.

There are a number of solutions on the market such as Ion Cube and Source guardian, but they all have the same flaw.

The additional step of decrypting the code will add a processing overhead and much like a DRM system all of the solutions on the market require that you have the encryption key available to the server running the code rendering the encryption trivial to defeat. It also introduces a load of new ways your code can go wrong.

An alternative approach is to supply the source as byte code or use PHPC or HipHop to supply the code as a C executable. This won't stop them using the application, but it will make it difficult for people to modify. I would personally only consider this approach for reasons of performance not for obfuscation.

Fundamentally the best way to deal with this issue is to make sure you have the right licences and agreements in place to cover you. Before you start a project it should always be clear who will own the source code at the end.

You get repeat work by delivering the best solution rather than locking customers in.

Answer (score 0):

Zend have product called [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) which can obfuscate your source code.

Another solution would be to deliver an already compiled version, you can use [`php compiler`](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) or [`phalanger`](http://www.php-compiler.net/).

Note: the obfuscation wouldn't block the user from using the code but would make it really difficult to upgrade/modify it. My opinion delivering a compiled version or just signing a proper contract would be the best options

Comment: @sage29: I never used Zend Guard but I imagine it work on any projects, same goes for the php compiler...

Comment: I tried it some time ago, and it worked with any code, but it requires the server to have installed the extension.

Comment: @SeRPRo: ha so it might do the same kind of stuff as a compiler, convert the php code to some bycode and use directly the php virtual machine